# Product images are not uploading while saving

Tags: magento2, image, image-upload

Product images are not uploading while saving the products. This happens only when I try to update the product. After trying to save the image, it throws an error and says,

> Update with id "0" does not exist.

I got the following exception in the log file.

> [2018-01-08 06:47:17] report.CRITICAL: Update with id "0" does not
>   exist. {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): Update
>   with id \"0\" does not exist. at
>   \vendor\magento\module-staging\Model\UpdateRepository.php:103)"}

What is causing the problem? Why is it happening? I don't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not happened only uploading the image. It happened whenever I tried to update the products. I checked the imported sheet multiple times and I came to know that the sheet did not have the attribute **created_at**. After keeping that attribute in the sheet, It works fine. And I could able to update the products.